# Android ChimpChat pressing backspace

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I'm trying to use ChimpChat for a project which includes injecting input events into a connected device.

There are methods
1.    void press(PhysicalButton key, TouchPressType type);
2.    void press(String keyName, TouchPressType type);

I'm able to use the 1st method properly through: iDevice.press(button, type);

However, I can't get the 2nd method to work. Trying something like iDevice.press ("A", type) does not type an "A" on the device, even though the following is logged:

Feb 27, 2012 4:58:36 PM com.android.chimpchat.ChimpManager sendMonkeyEventAndGetResponse
INFO: Monkey Command: key down A.

I was able to work around this by using

1. void type(String string);

Now my question is, how do I get the backspace key to work? Calling type("\b"); doesn't erase on the device.

Has anyone used the 2. void press(String keyName, TouchPressType type); method previously? If so, am I doing something wrong? I'm a bit confused by what keyName is supposed to be. If not, does any one know how to send the backspace character to the device?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last I looked `ChimpManager` has a few more methods than the `IDevice` exposes.  You can access the other methods via `device.getManager()`. One of those methods that might help you is `press(PhysicalButton)`.  So you *should* be able to get the backspace to work like this:

```
device.getManager().press(PhysicalButton.BACK)
```

[Look at the source](http://androidxref.com/source/xref/sdk/chimpchat/src/com/android/chimpchat/ChimpManager.java) for more insight to how it all works.

**UPDATE:**

Oops, you're looking for the backspace! According to the `monkey` README:

> key [down|up] keycode
>
> This command injects KeyEvent's into the input system.  The keycode
>   parameter refers to the KEYCODE list in the KeyEvent class 
>   (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html).
>   The format of that parameter is quite flexible.  Using the menu key as
>   an example, it can be 82 (the integer value of the keycode),
>   KEYCODE_MENU (the name of the keycode), or just menu (and the Monkey
>   will add the KEYCODE part).  Do note that this last part doesn't work
>   for things like KEYCODE_1 for obvious reasons.

So looking at the KeyEvent class you should be able to use:

```
device.getManager().keyDown("KEYCODE_DEL") // Backspace according to KeyEvent
// OR
device.getManager().keyDown("67")
```

Comment: PhysicalButton.BACK refers to the physical "back" button that takes you to the previous page. The button I'm looking for is "Backspace" that deletes the previous character.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked!

Just a quick question - where could I find the key names for each key (for example that backspace was "KEYCODE_DEL")?